# How to show this matrix operation is true in terms of $\Sigma = Diag(\pi)- \pi \pi^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two $k-1$ dimensional column vectors $\pi=(\pi_1,...,\pi_{k-1})^T$ and $p=(p_1,...,p_{k-1})^T$, where $\pi_i, p_i \in (0,1)$, for $i=1,...,k-1$, and $0< \Sigma_{i=1}^{k-1} \pi_i, \Sigma_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i<1$, and a $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ matrix $\Sigma = Diag(\pi)- \pi \pi^T$, with $Diag(\pi)=Diag(\pi_1,...,\pi_{k-1})$, show that

$$(p-\pi)^T \Sigma^{-1} (p-\pi) = \Sigma_{i=1}^k \frac{(p_i - \pi_i)^2}{\pi_i}$$, where $\pi_k = 1-\Sigma_{i=1}^{k-1} \pi_i, p_k=1- \Sigma_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i$

How to solve out this question? I am stuck that how to derive the $\Sigma^{-1}.$

Comment: Use [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks. It is a good hint. But I cannot derive the desired equation.